# Google Cloud Dataflow: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' when running integration test

Tags: integration-testing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an apache beam pipeline that works fine in both local and cloud modes. However, I have an end to end integration tests that I'm running in every MR, and the IT is submitted to Dataflow.

This time, the IT is throwing the following error:

```
_import_module return __import__(import_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

The stacktrace is not pointing at all to the place where the module is not recognised. Just the follwing:

```
job-v2-test-20-08160911-vs73-harness-drt8
      Root cause: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 285, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module
    return __import__(import_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

The main module I use only in the IT file, and it doesn't exist in any transformation of the pipeline. Also, when I run the IT, half of the pipeline transformation runs successfully until it hangs with the provided error

The IT code:

```
from main import run
import argparse

import unittest
import logging


class PipelineIT(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.test_pipeline = TestPipeline(is_integration_test=True)

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self.args, self.beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
        self.pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(self.beam_args)
        self.client = get_bq_instance()
        self.tables_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")

    def test_mc_end_to_end(self):

        state_verifier = PipelineStateMatcher(PipelineState.DONE)
        extra_opts = {
            'input': IT_BUCKET,
            'output_dataset': IT_DATASET,
            'output': IT_OUTPUT,
            'bq_timestamp': self.tables_timestamp,
            'on_success_matcher':
                all_of(state_verifier)
        }

        run(self.test_pipeline.get_full_options_as_args(**extra_opts), save_main_session=True)

# buch of asserts
```

THe command I'm using to run the IT

```
coverage run -m  pytest --log-cli-level=INFO integration_tests/end_to_end_it_test.py --job_name "end_to_end_it" --test-pipeline-options=" --run_mode=cloud --mode=test --setup_file=path_to_setup.py"
```

The pipeline works fine in the production mode, but in the testing mode it shows that error.
I'm just wondering if the `main` is used only to trigger the integration test from local, how can it breaks the pipeline with the error

Answer (score 1):

After deep investigation, in my pipeline, I was using `beam.Filter` in the following way:

```
dropped_and_missing = all_recs | 'Filter Dropped and Missing recs' >> beam.Filter(lambda rec: rec['existing_status'] == 'Dropped' or rec['existing_status'] == 'Missing')
```

Replacing the code block with a `PTransformation` that is based on `if` conditions solved the issue.

I don't know where the issue is, I tried to dig into the source code, checking if there is in main module in the `Filter` function, but it doesn't exist.

Also what's suspicious is the error is occurred only when running the integration test from the command line. Pipeline works fine with `LocalRunner` and `DataflowRunner`

Comment: Note that TestPipeline is only intended for Beam integration testing. Consider using DirectRunner or a different runner for your tests in other repos.

Comment: Usually I'm using DirectRunner for debugging and DataflowRunner for production, and when it comes to tests I use TestDirectRunner for the transformation integration test and TestDirectRunner for the end to end integration test. So test runners are basically based on the Direct and DF runners.